# LDAP provider returns referral

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

So i have an LDAP server that has one port that directs to LDAP consumers and an other port that directs to LDAP providers. However when i make a write request using php's `ldap_add` function the LDAP provider is throwing a `code 10 : Referral` error (this is the error that wants me to follow the referral)

Why do i have to follow the referral when i am already talking to the master/provider server ?

From what i read only a slave/consumer should send back a referral when you try to write to that server. ( as you are not allowed to write to a consumer )

Answer (score 0):

Not at ldap_add function specifically, but I constantly got this error after binding ldap, and trying to get data via ldap_search. I figured out my problem was that I put DC entries in parentheses in "base domain" parameter. Check out if that's the case!

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening consistently, there may be an error in your master server's configuration.  I know when my group had been trying to use a test server that had one port for the supplier and another port for the consumer, we would often find that changes we had meant to make on one of the LDAP server instances wound up on the other server.  Looking up the OpenLDAP's administrator's guide online, it looks like they may have left an example referral in the standard config file as well.  Look for a line that says something like

```
referral         ldap://root.openldap.org
```

I haven't been able to find a reference that states exactly how one would set up a referral on update configuration for OpenLDAP, so I can't tell you exactly what you're looking for.

If it is only happening intermittently, predominantly when the server is at high load, and the redirect is to another supplier server that's part of the same cluster of LDAP servers, that would be perfectly normal attempts from the servers to try to balance out their load. This redirection probably means that it's not only actively working on doing another change, but it's either a change it expects to take some time, such that queueing on the supplier server you connected to would not be prudent, or it's already filled its queue for pending requests, so there isn't anywhere to queue any change you requested.